# Spring OAuth2Login() and distributed security session

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am using Spring Security 5.2 and Keycloak as an Authorization Server. So far, I have set up backend services as resource servers and client.

Now I am looking to set up an angular front end with a controller protected by spring security. In the Spring Security Reference, on OAuth2Login(), specifically the section  [Spring Boot 2.x Sample](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#oauth2login-sample-boot-application) says the following:
"At this point, the OAuth Client retrieves your email address and basic profile information from the UserInfo Endpoint and establishes an authenticated session."

Additionally, after turning on OAuth2Login(), I have observed that the angular front end does not get/manage a JWT token or need to add it to the http header, which is very convenient.

However, does this mean that I need to set up a distributed session manager, ala redis, in order to manage this security session in a distributed deployment. I have been assuming that using OAuth2 and JWT obviated such a requirement..

Comment: What do you mean by *in order to manage this security session in a distributed deployment*? What do you want to manage? What is distributed?

Comment: I want to distribute the controller using spring security across multiple instances.
For example, multiple instances behind a load balancer.
In that case, I would need to use a sticky session or distributed session.
In OAuth2, passing a JWT token does away with the need for either of these solutions, since the token can  be validated & used on any instance.
But in Spring OAuth2Login, it looks like there is no JWT token passed to the front end app.

Comment: You already know two solutions: sticky session, distributed session. Another way is to use Spring Gateway Zuul. However, you could also use JWT, see https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-openid-connect